# Add event to a programmatically generated UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview

So I have a method then when called generates a simple UIView with some labels in it:

```
UIView *view1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 300, 250)];
view1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
view1.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[self.view addSubview:view1];
```

I call this method 6 times so it places 6 UIViews (I give them different coordinates of course) around the screen.

How can I detect when a user swipes right on one of them and then trigger some other method?
I've tried something like this:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(myLabel1Tap)];
swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
[view1 addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];
```

and then a method:

```
- (void)myLabel1Tap {
}
```

But I'm not sure what to do inside that method, how can I know which view was swiped if they are all called the same 'view1'?

Comment: Don't abuse the Xcode tag, this is completely unrelated to Xcode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change the gesture recognizers selector to accept an argument (by adding a colon after the method signature)

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(myLabel1Swipe:)];
```

this will mean the gesture recognizer will get passed in, and then you can perform actions based on the gesture recognizers properties, e.g.

```
- (void)myLabel1Swipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recogniser
{
    UIView *swipedView = [recognizer view];
    //do whatever you want with this view
}
```

Comment: Great, that's what I needed!
Ho can I refer to the objects within that view? if in that view there is a label called myLabel how could I hide it let's say.
something like:
swipedView.myLabel.hidden = YES;

Comment: there are a few ways but the simplest is to set the tag property of that view when adding it to the swipedView (`myLabel.tag = 12`), then you can access it with `UILabel *myLabel = [swipedView viewWithTag:12];`